# How to show the integrated image which has different type

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a image which generated from 4 images. Each image has different type as the code

```
nrow=256;
ncol=256;
%% Image with double type
I1=randi(256,[nrow ncol]);
%% Image with float type in range 
r2 = randn(nrow*ncol,1);
I2=reshape(r2,[nrow ncol]);
I3=I2.*20;
%% Binary image
I4=randi([0 1],[nrow ncol]);
%% make row images
I_int=[I1;I2;I3;I4]
imshow(I_int,[]);
```

However, the imshow can not show the above `I_int` image. It only show the image I3 and I2, while other I1,I4 are black. How can I use imshow to show above image with its detail? Thank all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the datatypes of your variables *are not* different (I'm a little confused why you think they are). It is always a good idea to use [`class`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) to check this.

```
cellfun(@class, {I1, I2, I3, I4}, 'uni', 0)

   'double'    'double'    'double'    'double'
```

The difference in display intensity is because the dynamic range of each of your subimages is *very* different.

- `I1` between 1 and 256
- `I2` between 0 and 1
- `I3` between 0 and 20
- `I4` between 0 and 1

As a result, when you combine them and display them using `imshow`, `imshow` (with the second input specified as `[]`) sets axes [`clims`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#prop_CLim) to fit the `min` and `max` of your data. So black is set to 0 and white is 256. Because of this, `I2` and `I4` will appear mostly black since all of their pixels are between 0 and 1 which is much less than 256.

To fix this, you could normalize all the data (using [`mat2gray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/mat2gray.html)) prior to concatenation and display.

```
I_int = cat(1, mat2gray(I1), mat2gray(I2), mat2gray(I3), mat2gray(I4));
```

[image]

Alternately, you could display each of these images in their own axes where they will get their own `clims` that match their dynamic range.

Comment: Yes. Your are right. It is different range. You used the normalization method. However, if I want to show the raw image of each images, Is it possible by integrated image?

Comment: @user8430 Based on what I said in my post, it's clear that it isn't possible with them in the same image. You would have to create 4 separate axes with images (as I said at the end) and honestly that will look exactly like the normalized approach above the only difference is that you could use the data cursor to examine the *real* values with that approach.